# How to compare the values of two pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

My function below always returns true. I assume is because I'm comparing pointers. How can I compare the values and not just the pointers.

```
struct Card {
    const char *suit;
    const char *face;
};

...
struct Card hand[HAND_SIZE];
...

//Determine whether the hand contains a pair.
bool hasPair(struct Card wHand[]) {
    bool result = false;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < HAND_SIZE; ++i) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < HAND_SIZE; ++j) {
            if(wHand[i].face == wHand[j].face && wHand[i].suit == wHand[j].suit) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why are they declared constant in your struct?

Comment: Thats because you compare a card with itself.

Comment: In addition to  the comparison with itself issue that others have raised, a **pair** in most card games is two cards with the same *face* value, but not necessarily the same *suit*.  You seem to be comparing for identical cards, when you likely just need to be comparing on face.

Comment: @selbie. Thanks you are right.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem with this algorithm is that you are comparing the card with itself: you start both `i` and `j` at zero, so you get false positives for pairing each card with itself.

A simple fix to this is to start `j` at `i+1`, ensuring that only different cards get compared.

Since setting `result` to `true` is a one-way street, consider returning `true` as soon as you find a match:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < HAND_SIZE; ++i) {
    for (unsigned j = i+1; j < HAND_SIZE; ++j) {
        if(wHand[i].face == wHand[j].face && wHand[i].suit == wHand[j].suit) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

**Note:** This assumes that `face` and `suit` are set to string constants in the same code, which may be fragile if you link multiple object files. A much safer option for this would be using an `enum` for face and suit representation, and making an array of string representations for each `enum` value:

```
enum Face {
    Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace
};
enum Suit {
    Spades, Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts
};
struct Card {
    enum Face face;
    enum Suit suit;
};
```

Comment: also are we sure that it will work? because `strcmp` would be much safer here.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I was about to add a note to that effect, except I suggested using `enum`s in place of C strings. Thank you!

Comment: @dasbinkenlight Thanks. It still return true thought

Comment: @user2300867 That's odd. Are you sure there's no pair in the hand, though?

Answer (score 1):

`result` is set to true in the first (and, as it happens, in every) iteration of your i loop, given that at some point in each iteration, `j==i` and therefore you're comparing the same array element with itself. You should only execute your if statement when `i!=j`.

To your original point though, you're not comparing pointers - you are comparing the actual values. The array [ ] square brackets serve to dereference the pointer;
`wHand[i]` does the same thing as `*(wHand + i)`.

Comment: @thharrison. Thanks clarifying. Just started with C and still get confuse with pointers.